# Vue Vuetify open dialog component onclick

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**Edit**: I figured out why the dialog isnt opening. The child component is not receiving the `openComment` event. I checked in the root component, and that is receiving the event correctly. Any suggestions on why sibling components are not receiving the events? It could also be because I am not using the component in anything, but because it is the modal itself, I dont really want to import it to any other `vue` file.

I am trying to figure out a way to open a modal dialog from my toolbar. The toolbar lives in one component file, and the dialog lives in another component file. I am trying to acheive this using events, but i cant seem to get it to trigger. What i have tried is sending a custom even which is supposed to see the set the vmodel for the dialog to true. I am using Vuetify to create the dialogs.

My dialog component file is:

```
<template>
<v-dialog persistent
    v-model="commentDialog"
    transition="dialog-transition">
    <v-card>
    <v-card-title primary-title>
        Add a comment
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
        <v-text-field label="Legal first name*" required></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
    </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from '../main'
export default {
name: 'CommentModal',
data() {
    return {
    commentDialog: false
    }
},
created() {
    bus.$on('openComment', function () {
    this.commentDialog = true
    })
},
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

The toolbar component includes the following:

```
<template>
<v-btn fab small
    @click="commentThis($event)"
    <v-icon>fas fa-comment</v-icon>
</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
commentThis: function (e) {
    bus.$emit('openComment')
}
</script>
```

Bonus and follow up question to this question would be how can i see the event bus on the vue chrome debugger?

Comment: Could you provide your `bus` code

Comment: try this :
bus.$on('openComment', () => {
       this.commentDialog = true 
     })

Comment: @Pvl what is `bus` code? It is the simple `export const bus = new Vue()` in main.js. @radu, your syntax my my syntax is the same, so same result. Nothing triggers.

Comment: Seems like you event triggered. But problem with dialog itself. Isn't it?

Comment: @Pvl i tried that theory first. i copied the modal dialog template from vuetify to test this theory, but thats not it it seems like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It seems like i had to call the component somewhere in my toolbar component vue file. So i called it as ` and that enables the CommentModal component to react the the sent events. If the component is not called anywhere in the sibling components, then it does not react to any of the events.

But I would love to hear if there is a better solution to this. It feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: This isn't hackish at all. The component must be under vue's control for it to receive events. Think about this another way: if your component isn't a modal, where should vue place show it? There is no information about this in the component itself. A component that isn't attached to the app, some how in the chain, it's not rendered. Webpack (or any other module builder) could even remove the entire code from your distribution if it's never used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with function context

```
created() {
    const self = this
    bus.$on('openComment', function () {
    self.commentDialog = true
    })
},
```

or

```
bus.$on('openComment', () => (this.commentDialog = true))
```

> Bonus and follow up question to this question would be how can i see the event bus on the vue chrome debugger?

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const bus = new Vue()

window.__myBus = bus

export { bus }
```

Comment: That doesnt trigger the modal. If i switch to es6 fat arrow functions, then i dont have to use `const self = this` because the this context will resolve correctly inside the function. Regardless, i tried your theory, but that doesnt trigger the modal.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine if to solve context issue

Comment: I put in a console.log inside the callback, and it seems like it is never getting triggered. maybe that is why the modal is not opening.

Comment: Do you use the same bus object?